# Enabling static pin for bluetooth authentication BlueZ (Linux) error in bt-agent

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, dbus, bluez

I am trying to enable a static pin/password authentication entry for devices that are trying to connect to my raspberry pi. I have tried various methods including using bt-agent tools, while configuring sspmode to 0 using hciconfig. bt-agent tool sometimes works, but often times results in seg faults. Are there any better alternatives to enable a static pin on my bluetooth connection?

I have done some further debugging with bt-agent tool. The bt-agent tool is able to correctly verify the password. The device is able to connect for a fraction of a second, but then error pops up in client device saying incorrect pin. Upon further debugging, I found in /var/log/syslog the following error pertaining to DBUS that happens exactly at pairing time: Agent /org/blueztools replied with an error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply, Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus).

FYI, I am using a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Which version of BlueZ are you using? Also, by static pin/password, do you mean that you want your pin/password to be set before the pairing begins?

Comment: BlueZ 5.23. Yes I want password to be set before the pairing begins, in legacy SSP mode. I have done some further debugging with bt-agent tool. The bt-agent tool is able to correctly verify the password. The device is able to connect for a fraction of a second, but then error pops up in client device saying incorrect pin. Upon further debugging, I found in /var/log/syslog the following error pertaining to DBUS that happens exactly at pairing time: agent /org/blueztools replied with an error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply, Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus).

Comment: That's quite an outdated version; maybe it's best if you switch to a more recent version. I'm not sure on how to enable static PIN but please check this answer as there are many ideas and suggestions:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888589/linux-command-line-howto-accept-pairing-for-bluetooth-device-without-pin